# Passing Javascript variable to '<a href' with 'window.location.href' in a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

As the title indicate I would like to pass a variable with javascript but in a frame
In the past I have this code :

```
  <a href="page.php" target="frame" onClick="$('#frame').show()">
```

Now I want to pass a variable, the code below can pass the variable but in another window but I  want it in the same frame.

```
 <a href="page.php" target="frame" onClick="location.href=this.href+'?var='+X;">
```

Comment: is it critical you use a frame?  Perhaps it would be better if you just *ajaxed* in some content - that way you don't have to worry about communication between frames

Answer (score 2):

I think you maybe able to use:

```
document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.location.href...
```

to change the href of the frame (and pass your variable), but I'm pretty sure it will require a refresh if you're using a query string.

Perhaps if you append a hash (`#var=something`) instead of a query string that will work without the refresh?

*Note that this probably won't work at all if you're doing your frame stuff across domains.*

Comment: could you expand on that a bit?  I haven't tested this code (nor will I likely create a test case), but I'd be happy to help you debug if you share any errors, or better yet, if you wanted to create a minimal test case and link it...

Comment: There was a typo in my code: `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById`.  Does that fix the issue?

Comment: I added the code bellow but he display the same page in the frame.

function redirect(){
$('#frame').show();   document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.location.href = "page.php?var="+X;}

<a href="#"  target="frame" onClick="redirect();">

Comment: the problem (I think) is that its loading the links href (`#`) as the default event handler of your `<a>` after `redirect()` has fired. Perhaps trying `function redirect(e){ ...; e.preventDefault; }` will work? Or maybe `return: false;` at the end of that function?  I can never remember when to use which ;-)

Comment: does it work if you just paste the code into the console, rather than trying it onClick? `$('#frame').show(); document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.lo‌​cation.href = "page.php?var="+X;` (you'll have to make sure `X` is defined in the global scope, or replace it with the value you want)

Comment: the first time when I click I see the current page, the second I see the page what I want the third the current ... and when i want to see it in another tab with ctrl I see all time the current page

Comment: sorry, but I'm pretty burned out on this now... hope I got you at least pointed in the right direction.  You can try fleshing out your question (or re-asking it) and adding in some code from what we've tried here.  I'd also suggest getting away from the `onClick` attribute in favor of adding the event handler more like `$('a.link').click(function(){ ... }`

Comment: also, idk if it was you, but it would be nice to get rid of that `-1` next to my answer - I hope this answer and its comments have at least *some* value to helping you solve your problem.

Comment: able to make any progress?

Comment: I asked again this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982625/passing-variable-to-a-frame-using-a-using-javascript) 
but no progress.. thank you

Comment: Now I can give you `1` :-) Thank you for help !