# Passing variable to a frame using '<a...' using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I want to pass a variable to the frame but I got the current page.

Code:

```
function redirect(e){
 $('#frame').show();
 document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.location.href = "page.php?var="+X;         
 e.preventDefault; 
}

<a href="#"  target="frame" onClick="redirect();"></a>
```

Comment: You can pass `X` to `redirect()` as a parameter.

Comment: What's the problem? In general, it seems fine. Care to explain if something isn't working or if you get certain errors? Can you not get the value of `X` (which is not defined) in your PHP?

Comment: Note that A) `e` will be `undefined` because you're not passing anything into `redirect`, and B) If it *were* an event object, `e.preventDefault;` would do nothing, since you're not *calling* the function (that would be `e.preventDefault();`). C) You're basically not using jQuery here.

Comment: And just wondering - if you're using jQuery, why are you still using inline event handlers? Use jQuery's `on` method to bind the "click" event

Comment: I got in the frame the `index.php` and not `page.php`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I made the following changes but in this case I get no page in the frame.
 `<a href="#"  target="frame" onClick="redirect(e);">` 
`e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Mils: That's because there's no `e` in scope where you're calling `redirect`. There is an `event` in scope, though, so: `onClick="redirect(event);"` But again, why are you using a DOM0 attribute-based event handler a'la 1996 when here in 2013 there are so many better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have gotten it working: http://jsfiddle.net/LrBau/1/

```
<a href="#" class="redirect-link">redirect</a>

<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

<script>

  var X = 'testVal';

  var redirect = function() {
    $('#frame').show().attr('src', "page.php?var=" + X);        
    return false;
  };

  $('.redirect-link').click( redirect );

</script>
```